# How to print log from FME when run from python script?

Tags: arcpy, fme-form, python-toolbox, spatial-etl

I created a Spatial ETL ToolBox in ArcCatalog.
When I run the tool from ArcCatalog I see log massages.
But when I run this tool from a python script, the logs do not print to the python console.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"c:\Toolbox123.tbx")
arcpy.SpatialETLTool(param1,param2,...)
```

How to print log from FME when running from python script?

Comment: http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Error_Unexpected_Behavior/Logging-with-Python-scripts 8th September 2014

Comment: I dont want to create owne log. I want print log from any Transformer with I use in SpatialETLTool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not familiar with FME - but a search turned up some code that basically said

```
# echo log file to stdout
logFile = open(logFilename, 'r')
for line in logFile.readlines():
    print line
```

from [here](https://eas.googlecode.com/svn/tags/Beta_v0.6/etl/etl_utils.py). So what @mapperz may be alluding to is creating a log file - then grabbing the output and writing to the console.

Comment: This print log when FME process end. I would like to display log immediately.

Comment: a config option? - http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_QuickTranslator/Default.htm#FME%20Configuration/LOG_STANDARDOUT.htm

Comment: Do You now wher/how can I set this  parametr?

Comment: Not certain - you could try the method at [this page](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004m0000000t000000.htm) that says 'To configure FME Workbench to generate a (.log) file each time you run a translation, click Tools > FME Options, click Runtime on the navigation menu, then check the Save log to file check box.'